# how to change min-height of one div to height of another div in jquery - code not working

Tags: jquery, html, dynamic, css

I have searched and toyed with this code based on the many answers to similar problems found here and on other sites -- I think it should work, but it's not. I must be missing something.

I want to dynamically change the height of the sidebar div to be the same height of the left div, if the left div is greater than the original min-height. There is no background image in either div, but there is a border that is important to the design and that border ends at the min-height.

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js">
  $(document).ready(function() {
    var leftHeight = $('#left-area').height();
    var sidebarHeight = $('#sidebar').height();

    if( leftHeight > 690 ) {
      $('#sidebar').css('min-height' , leftHeight+'px' );
      }
    else {
      }
    });
  </script>
```

Comment: You need separate script tags for the jQuery library and your script's code.

Comment: thank you Fabricio ... yes, that was the issue, it seems. Now it works on most of the pages -- there's one holdout page I have to debug. 

here's the url: [link] (http://174.132.168.130/~samlewis/?page_id=26)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to separate your javascript:

Also, you don't need the 'px'.

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
  $(document).ready(function() {
    var leftHeight = $('#left-area').height();
    var sidebarHeight = $('#sidebar').height();

    if( leftHeight > 690 ) {
      $('#sidebar').css('min-height' , leftHeight);
      }
    else {
      }
    });
</script>
```

If you ever run into javascript errors, you can always check the console.

Comment: Ok, first thing is you should always check the console. If you look [here](http://s3.kkloud.com/gett/2zV37uU/Screen%20shot%202013-01-07%20at%204.14.59%20PM.png.0x675.u1c8t56r4kzhyqfr00aefo11cult0529.png) you'll notice there are two errors in your own code. Firstly, it says `$` is not defined. This is because you commented out the jQuery script, seen [here](http://s3.kkloud.com/gett/5m2f7uU/Screen%20shot%202013-01-07%20at%204.17.57%20PM.png.0x675.rl0kaxxnxcb1q0k9vo0lfz4roqykqpvi.png).

Comment: Second, you have a random `if` statement with only a beginning parenthesis, seen [here](http://s3.kkloud.com/gett/2Of98uU/Screen%20shot%202013-01-07%20at%204.20.09%20PM.png.0x675.jktwlvp1lhw1m7vi9aesh3g27qskbj4i.png). You also try making a new `<script>` tag and never close it. You should fix all those errors, but mainly uncomment the jQuery import, since you need that for the code to work.